# parselyjs and webpack on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have a rails project with webpacker

I have run `yarn install parselyjs` and I have a pack file:

`javascript/packs/parsely.jsx`

which contains

```
import parsely from 'parsleyjs';
```

I am importing this packfile into my view like so:

`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'parsely' %>`

However, when I try to call `parsley();` in console, I get:

`ReferenceError: parsley is not defined`

How can I get parsely to work when using webpacker in a rails project?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a separate `javascript_pack_tag` you can require it in `javascript/packs/application.js`...

`require("packs/parsely")`

Comment: Yes, thank you for the suggestion, but this particular page in my app doesn't need all of the other libs in my application pack, which is why I split it out